# Laravel 5.6 Facade/Alias not registering/working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to make my own custom Facade and register is with a custom service container and finally creating a custom alias for this facade.

I am not sure what part is not working, maybe there is a problem with the service container registering or maybe with the alias?

Let's start with my facade:

```
/**
 *
 * @see \App\Library\Facades\ViewWrapper\CustomView
*/
class CustomViewFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'customview';
    }
}
```

My CustomView class with the logic and the `show` function

```
namespace App\Library\Facades\ViewWrapper;

...

class CustomView
{
    public function show(...) { ... }

    ...
}
```

My CustomViewServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

...  

class CustomViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CustomViewFacade::class);
        $this->app->alias(CustomViewFacade::class, 'customview');
    }
}
```

How I register the provider in the `config\app.php`

```
App\Providers\CustomViewServiceProvider::class,
```

How I create the alias in the `config\app.php`

```
'CustomView' => App\Library\Facades\ViewWrapper\CustomViewFacade::class
```

In my controller I use the facade like this:

```
use CustomView;

...

public function show(ImageRequest $imagerequest)
{
    return CustomView::show(...);
}
```

I get the following error in the controller:

> Class 'CustomView' not found

What am I doing wrong here?

### EDIT

After clearing config and composer autoload dump I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method App\Library\Facades\ViewWrapper\CustomViewFacade::show()

Comment: please try  php artisan cache:clear and composer dumpautoload -o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you haven't quite clearly understood how Facades work. They are just an easy way to access your services without having to deal with dependency injection. I'm not a fan of this methodology, but here's how you do it properly.

1. You need to bind your actual service to the container, not the facade. The facade is almost just a symbolic link to your service within the container.
2. You need to import the actual service, not the facade. Laravel will automatically bind your dependency in the type-hinted variable, thanks to its behind the scenes magic.

Use:

```php
use App\Library\Facades\ViewWrapper\CustomView;
```

(small note: your namespace here should be your service's namespace, be aware to not mix up the semantic between facade and service. The service contains the logic, the facade is just an accessor to a service that is already injected. This is important!!)

Instead of:

```php
use CustomView;
```

It should solve the issue.

Also, I'd suggest you do define how the class should be constructed and injected in the Service Container by using a Closure in the `bootstrap` function.

```php
class CustomViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(CustomView::class, function () {
            return new CustomView(...);
        );
    }
}
```

Also, the alias function is not necessary in your case. It'd simply allow you to access the service by using the `customview` key in the Service Container.

Just define the Facade in your config/app.php file.

Another small suggestion: use PHP 7 class selectors instead of strings in your facade accessor definition. For example: `CustomView::class` intead of `customview`. It makes your code neater and easier to read.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "Just define the Facade in your boostrap file"?

Comment: My bad. Check out `config/app.php`.

Comment: So should I use the CustomViewFacade or not? I am a bit confused

Comment: Yes, add a line in the aliases array like it's already done by default. Ie: `'CustomView' => Namespace\To\CustomView\Facade\CustomViewFacade::class`...

Comment: I deleted the facade and it works now, for what reason should I add the facade?

Comment: The facade is to access your service in your code by using `CustomView::show(...)` without having to dependency-inject it somewhere in a variable.

Comment: I just use the CustomView class as you showed and do this in my controller `return CustomView::show(...);` and it works

Comment: It probably means the alias is working. Have you added the line in the `aliases` array of `config/app.php`?

Comment: Nope I removed the alias line and did a config clear and a composer dump autoload and it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186290/discussion-between-giampy-and-michael).

Comment: Come in the chat please

Answer (score 1):

Please run below command and check:

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: I now get this error `Call to undefined method App\Library\Facades\ViewWrapper\CustomViewFacade::show()`